# Time complexity of nested loops where k < j < i < n

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

I would like to know the time complexity of this algorithm and how it is calculated.

```
for (i = 1; i < 2n; i++) {
    for (j = 1; j < i; j++) {
        for (k = 1; k < j; k++) {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume the inner statement takes constant time.

The inner loop runs `(j-1)` times, hence its run time is

```
t_inner(j) = Sum {k from 1 to j-1} 1
           = j-1
```

The middle loop runs `i-1` times. Its run time is:

```
t_middle(i) = Sum { j from 1 to i-1 } t_inner(j)
            = Sum { j from 1 to i-1 } j-1
            = 1/2 * (2 - 3 * i + i^2)
```

The outer loop runs `2n-1` times. Its run time is:

```
t_outer(n) = Sum { i from 1 to 2n-1 } t_middle(i)
           = Sum { i from 1 to 2n-1 } 1/2 * (2 - 3 * i + i^2)
           = 1/3 (-3 + 11 n - 12 n^2 + 4 n^3)
```

From the last formula, we see that the time complexity is `O(n^3)`.